# How do I edit Azure SQL Database using pyodbc/odbc?

Tags: python, sql, database, azure, pyodbc

I wrote a Python program that web scraped a website and added the results to a Microsoft Access database. I now want to run the script again, with it adding the data to an Azure SQL database. I keep getting this error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I have tried t edit the settings of the database to no avail. Could someone tell me what settings to apply to the database? I also tried to see if there was a way to run the Python script inside azure to try to avoid the problem. Is this possible?

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Database=sizedb3;Uid={your_user_name};Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')
```

I tried this driver. I have downloaded the driver from Microsoft's website. This driver is a connection string in the ODBC section of the Azure SQL database in the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the below python code to connect to Azure SQL DB with Azure AD authentication.

**Code:-**

```py
import pyodbc

  

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'

'Server=tcp:siliconserver.database.windows.net,1433;'

'Database=silicondb;'

'Uid=xxxser@sid24desaioutlook.onmicrosoft.com;'

'Pwd=xxxxxxxxxx@123;'

'authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')

  
  

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM StudentReviews')

  

for  i  in  cursor:

print(i)

  

cursor.close()

conn.close()
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Make sure you have allowed your Client IP in your Azure SQL server Networking tab like below:-

[image]

**I tried to remove one syntax/spelling from my Azure SQL connection string and got the** **same error code as yours** **like below:-**

[image]

You can validate your connection string server spelling and syntax from your Azure SQL server DB > Connection String > like below:-

[image]

Also, Make sure you have added your client IP and allowed it in your Azure SQL Server like below:-

[image]